# Why am i not getting the right button when a user like comment reply

Tags: python, jquery, django

i am working on a website where users can comment on a post and also other users can reply to comments on a post and like each comments. I have implemented a comment and like section, but when a user like a comment reply, the right icon do not display (a red heart). I am using heart for like button, just like instagram. When i click on the empty heart button, it gets the value in database but the empty heart do not change to red heart. This problem only occur in comment reply like.

Note: On the image i attached the red heart is my comment, that works well. But the empty heart is comment reply like, when clicked it gets count to 1 but the heart do not change to red, how do i make the heart turn red? that is the solution i want.

[image]

Model:

```
def comment_like_view(request):
    # post = get_object_or_404(Comments, id=request.POST.get('comment_id'))
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    comment.liked_comment = False
    if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = True

    context = {'comment': comment}

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('ajax_commentlikes.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

views:

```
def comment_like_view(request):
    # post = get_object_or_404(Comments, id=request.POST.get('comment_id'))
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    comment.liked_comment = False
    if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = True

    context = {'comment': comment}

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('ajax_commentlikes.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

comments.html:

```
{% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
<h6 class="comment editcomment-text ml-5">
{{ reply.comment_post }}
</h6>
<li id="user-comment">
<span class="commentlikes">{% include 'ajax_commentreplylikes.html' %}</span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

ajax_commentreplylike.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'site:comment_like' %}" method="POST" id="user-comment{{ reply.id }}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if reply.liked_comment %}
      <button type="submit" name="comment_id" value="{{ reply.id }}" class="like-comment animated fadeIn" style="background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;">
      <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/heartred24px.png" width="12" height="12">
      </button>

      {% if reply.likes.all|length > 999 %}
      <a href="{% url 'site:comment_likes_users' reply.id %}">
      <span class="dark-grey-text animated fadeIn" style="font-size:10px;font-weight:500;position:relative;left:-3px;">
      {{ reply.likes.count|human_format }}</span>
      </a>
      {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'site:comment_likes_users' reply.id %}">
      <span class="dark-grey-text animated fadeIn" style="font-size:10px;font-weight:500;position:relative;left:-3px;">
      {{ reply.likes.count }}</span>
      </a>
      {% endif %}

      {% else %}
      <button type="submit" name="comment_id" value="{{ reply.id }}" class="like-comment" style="background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;">
         <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/heart24px.png" width="12" height="12" alt="like">
       </button>

       {% if reply.likes.all|length > 999 %}
      <a href="{% url 'site:comment_likes_users' reply.id %}">
      <span class="dark-grey-text animated fadeIn">
      {{ reply.likes.count|human_format }}</span>
      </a>
      {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'site:comment_likes_users' reply.id %}">
      <span class="dark-grey-text animated fadeIn">
      {{ reply.likes.count }}</span>
      </a>
      {% endif %}        
      {% endif %}
  </form>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //LIKE USER COMMENT AND REPLY
  $(document).on('click', '.like-comment', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var pk = $(this).attr('value');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'site:comment_like' %}",
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
    data: {'id':pk},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#user-comment'+pk).html(response['form'])
      console.log($('#user-comment'+pk).html(response['form']));
    },
    error: function(rs, e) {
      console.log(rs.resopnseText);
   },
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check in the admin interface for that model and look if there is any changes when you click the button.

Comment: @Shanks... when i clicked on the empty heart, it shows that a user liked the reply comment which rise like count to 1. But the problem is that, if the current user clicked on the empty heart button, and rises like count to one, then the empty heart button will change to the red heart button, indicating that the current user liked the comment.